# Find a viewmodel in a viewmodelcollection

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm pretty new to MVVM and I'm trying to create a basic login screen, Which the user can enter Username and Password, and then I want to validate the information.

I have a userModel, as well as a UserViewModel and a UserViewModelCollection, which are wired up to the database.

So I'm trying to figure out how to search for, or find, the Matching UserViewModel, contained in the UserCollectionViewModel, based on the UserName entered in the login screen.

This is my user model

```
 public partial class user
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string USERNAME { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATEDDATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MOBILEDEVICE_ID { get; set; }
    public bool ALLOWNOTIFICATIONS { get; set; }
    public bool ISACTIVE { get; set; }
    public bool ISDELETED { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LASTMODIFIED_DATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LASTMODIFIEDBY_ID { get; set; }
}
```

In addtion I've created  a LoginViewModel to handle the login proceedure.

Everything is connected to my database and populates no problem, the issue is that I cant seem to figure out how to search through the userCollectionViewModel to find the usermodel, based on the UserName that is typed in.

I have an event handler in the LoginViewModel, which fires on Update while entering userName and Password

```
  public class LoginViewModel
{

    public virtual user CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentUserCredentialsValid { get; private set; }
    // 

    public void Init()
    {
        this.CurrentUser = new user();
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        IsCurrentUserCredentialsValid = userCollectionViewModel.Check(CurrentUser.USERNAME, CurrentUser.PASSWORD);
    }
    public static LoginViewModel Create()
    {
        return ViewModelSource.Create<LoginViewModel>();
    }
}
```

My question is, based on the UserName, passed to the Check routine in the UserCollectionViewModel, how do I actually find the UserViewModel contained in the UserCollectionViewModel.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Where is the code for your collection ?